# Audio noise when Bluetooth is connected

Tags: audio, noise, bluetooth

I'm making a Bluetooth speaker with a rechargeable Li-po battery. I had some noise coming from the speaker that I suppressed connecting a capacitor at the Bluetooth board's power source. Apparently I've gotten rid of the ground loop issue.

Now the speakers are silent when I power on, but when Bluetooth connects for audio, there's some signal noise coming from the speakers. The noise is gone when I disconnect Bluetooth, so it definitely has something to do with the Bluetooth wireless signal.

How can I get rid of this noise?

Things I've already done:

- The wire from Bluetooth to the amplifier is very short and I've wrapped it in aluminum foil to shield it.

What could possibly cause this:

- The Bluetooth board and amplifier need 5 V but I'm running them directly from a 3.7 V battery.

Here's my circuit (please see the diagram):

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you really should be using a slightly modern-ish Class-D amplifier instead of that archaic LM386 module. It would be at least an order of magnitude more efficient in energy usage.

Comment: I've tried to run several amplifiers on this same battery, and they all give way more noise for some reason. Tried different variants of PAM8403, PAM8610, TPA3110, TDA8932 etc

Want to use a single battery above and they all cause a lot of noise in speakers. 

LM386 gave the least noise.